# Spreadsheet Integration with website

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to integrate spreadsheet with my website. I want create one webpage with spreadsheet which allow users to edit content and also able to add new tab in sheet. Spreadsheet should allow all math functions like microsoft excel.

I have used [dhtmlxSpreadsheet](http://docs.dhtmlx.com/spreadsheet__index.html), but it is not allowing multiple tab functionality.

So is there any ready made tool or pulgins are available?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: `"all math functions like microsoft excel"` - you realise that that this is quite a large request, right? Is there anything specific you are having problems implementing? Or are you just looking for a plugin that has already done this?

Comment: Yes i have used "dhtmlxSpreadsheet" but it allows me to only single sheet not allowing tab functionality.